# Chat part of application - using UDP or TCP?

Tags: design-patterns, python, mysql, sockets

I'm trying to build a section of my app where two users can message each other. I've read about TCP and UDP and it seems like TCP is more suited due to ordered packet delivery. However, TCP requires a connection between the two users at all times for data to be sent but in my app one user may send another user a message even when the user receiving the message isn't on the application.

How do I get round this problem? I would ideally like to make the application P2P so I don't need a dedicated server but is the reality that I do need a dedicated server ran using TCP that can then delivers the messages when the user connects?

Or, alternatively I'm using mysql as the database to store the chat history so can I just load the latest messages off that when the users logs in?

Comment: [How does one decide between TCP and UDP?](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2014/01/27/how-does-one-decide-between-tcp-and-udp/#74d74c00664d)

Comment: Message persistence is a different problem.  Neither TCP or UDP have a solution for that.  If you want sent messages to arrive when the client later connects, you need some sort of persistent message store.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation of a persistant message store?

Comment: The one that most closely matches your specific requirements.  You'll have to do some research to figure that out.  Alternatively, you can try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you dont use some kind of server, the users need to open nat/firewalls ports for your chat to be able to send message into the client. You can use something like the sip protocol to solve this. (in many cases but not all) but still you need some way for client a to know where client b is. I would build something like this where the client connects to server with secure websocket. This is over tcp and https. In most cases https and websocket will work without any firewall/nat configurarion.

Comment: Would this work when client b isn't on the application or is this where I would use message storing in mysql?

Comment: I would highly recommend integrating with an existing chat service (like Slack, Jabber, etc.) rather than re-inventing the wheel completely.

Comment: If there's no server, how does user A find out user B's IP address?

Comment: Each user would be a server and when the server gets set up they would store their current IP address in a database. When a user wants to connect to another they find that users current IP address by their email address. I'm not sure this would work but would be my approach

Answer (score 1):

Please review carefully the suggestion made by Robert Harvey, above.

TCP requires you to "open a socket" and then guarantees two-way *ordered* conversations.  If you send three packets, they will all arrive and they will arrive in the sequence that you sent them.  You don't know and you don't care how many sockets the server might be talking to at any one time.  Your "request to connect" may be delayed or refused.

UDP puts a message into a bottle and tosses it into the sea.  It might never arrive.  It might arrive before or after some other bottle.  You will never know if it arrived.  You don't even know if the intended recipient is alive at all, much less pulling bottles out of the water.  The only way you'll know if your message was heard is if another bottle washes up on *your* shoreline, and you manage to grab it before it sinks.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend integrating your application to an existing chat solution.  Whether you use Slack, Jabber, or any other robust chat solution you no longer have to worry about the persistence problem and you don't have to maintain a custom solution.  I realize that Chat doesn't *feel* complicated, but the bottom line is that there are more things to consider than you think.

Your stated requirement:

> I do need a dedicated server ran ... that can then delivers the messages when the user connects

That requires a piece of persistent architecture that exists when the application is not currently running.  Your potential solutions are:

- Integrate with an existing chat solution (does not restrict you to your application, and can easily expand to new requirements you have)
- Persist using your database (I maintain an application with a poor-man's custom chat feature that does exactly that)
- Create a custom server to administrate and deliver chat messages

I would also look very hard at the reasons you are wanting to add Chat to your application.  The app I am maintaining with a custom poor-man's chat was created because a chat service didn't exist on that particular private network.  Rather than getting a proper chat server approved (and there are many), the original developers implemented their own.  In the context of what that application does, it is the most superfluous feature that should have been a completely separate service.

You may have very good reasons, and chat may be a more integral part of your application.  However, certain chat applications like Slack have an API that allows a level of integration that you wouldn't be able to accomplish on your own.  Take a good hard look at the decision to build another version of a chat server.

Comment: I'm definitely open to piggybacking on whatever's out there, however I've searched for information about Jabber but can't find much at all about it (tutorial docs/videos etc). Do you have any recommendations on tutorials about jabber, or other public XMPP services?

Comment: This might be a good start for XMPP compliant servers: https://xmpp.org/software/libraries.html .  That will allow you to send messages to the server once you've configured your client.  You'll need to connect to a server https://xmpp.org/software/servers.html that you install someplace.  If you have access to an XMPP compliant server already deployed, then you just need the client libraries.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that I need to use something like sleekxmpp or aioxmpp to pass the messages to a server such as IoT Broker or ejabberd, which I need to install on my computer? As the number of users messaging increase won't I need a better server than my computer, is it possible to use a cloud server and how would this work with IoT Broker or ejabberd.....or have I got this bit wrong?